# Text debating and co-writing software

Tags: web-apps, collaboration, voting

As part of advising an NGO, I am looking for web-based software to help them write texts, debate on them, amend them, and decide on them.

There are many web applications that are very close to what they need, but still missing some critical feature:

- [Google Documents](http://docs.google.com/) allows people to add suggestions and comments to the text that can be accepted/rejected. However, there is no voting system on each suggestion, or on the document as a whole, which is needed. There isn't a way to group suggestions together.
- Dedicated collaboration software [Adhocracy](https://adhocracy.plus/) allow people to comment text, with votes, but doesn't have suggestions, and doesn't allow users to make comments more precisely than a paragraph. [Loomio](https://www.loomio.org) does not allow for suggestions either.
- Github, with its pull requests that can have comments and emoji reactions could work in theory, but is very complex for non computer scientists or engineers.

Is there software that could fit my use-case?